# Collection view change spacing

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview

Problem: If number of lines with genres or countries(collection view cells) more than one , the last genre/country(cell) of the row clips to bound and cause space increasing.

[image: ScreenShot]

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)
    _ = cell.subviews.compactMap { $0.removeFromSuperview() }
    cell.layer.borderColor = Colors.textPoster.color().cgColor
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 3

    let label = self.label()

    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        label.text = ganres[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        label.text = countries[indexPath.row]
    }

    label.sizeToFit()
    cell.addSubview(label)
    label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    return cell
}

// MARK: UICollectionViewDelegate
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 8
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 8
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 0, height: 16)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let text = indexPath.section == 0 ? ganres[indexPath.row] : countries[indexPath.row]
    let size = CGSize(width: text.width(withConstrainedHeight: .greatestFiniteMagnitude, font: labelFont) + space, height: text.height(withConstrainedWidth: .greatestFiniteMagnitude, font: labelFont) + space)

    return size
}
```

Comment: you set it's with base on text so that problem is occurred.

Comment: so what could you recommend

Comment: either you can give fix with to all cell or other option is you can calculate first largest text and set all cell width to largest. 

or you can set label to 2 line or set width is fixed.

Comment: It might be good to state what you would like to happen instead.

Comment: Space should not be changed. I posted answer that I had found

Answer (score 0):

I have found answer [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/swift/comments/7f15s6/incorrect_spacing_between_cells_uicollectionview/). This FlowLayout use minimumInteritemSpacing to make left alignment. Make sure to set it by yourself.

```
class LeftAlignedCollectionViewFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
var cache: [IndexPath : UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes] = [:]

override func prepare() {
    cache = [:]
    super.prepare()
}

override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
    guard let originalAttributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect) else {
        return nil
    }
    var attributes = originalAttributes.map { $0.copy() as! UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes }
    var attributesByGraphicalRow: [[UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]] = []
    var y: CGFloat = 0
    var currentRow: [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes] = []

    func changeAttributesOfRow(_ row: [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]) {
        var minX: CGFloat = 0

        for rowAttribute in currentRow {
            let oldFrame = rowAttribute.frame
            let newOrigin = CGPoint(x: minX, y: oldFrame.origin.y)
            let newFrame = CGRect(origin: newOrigin, size: oldFrame.size)
            rowAttribute.frame = newFrame
            minX += (newFrame.size.width + self.minimumInteritemSpacing)
        }
    }

    for attribute in attributes {
        if attribute.frame.origin.y > y {
            // new row starts
            changeAttributesOfRow(currentRow)
            attributesByGraphicalRow.append(currentRow)
            currentRow = []
            y = attribute.frame.origin.y
        }
        currentRow.append(attribute)
    }
    if currentRow.count > 0 {
        // last row isn't appended in for loop
        changeAttributesOfRow(currentRow)
        attributesByGraphicalRow.append(currentRow)
    }

    for attribute in attributes {
        cache[attribute.indexPath] = attribute
    }
    return attributes
}

override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
    if let attribute = cache[indexPath] {
        return attribute
    }
    // now what??
    return super.layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath)
}
```

}